# Long term storage of equipment like buckets and kegs, lines, etc

Tags: equipment, kegging, storage

I'm moving, so I'm emptying my kegs (not down the drain!), and as I go I'm cleaning lines, emptying buckets, disassembling taps, etc.; and trying to figure out how best to store everything (assume it will be up to a year out of use).

What are recommended methods of storing lines, kegs, carboys, etc so they will not be ruined by dust or mold and so they will be easy to clean when I'm ready to put them back in service?

Answer (score 2):

As long as everything gets cleaned and dried, there should be no special precautions necessary after that for storing them.

Answer (score 1):

Once items are empty, give them a thorough washing to remove any debris. After the washing, use a sanitizer to kill any microbes. Allow everything to thoroughly air dry (hoses may need to be blown out to dry). Once completely dry, cover items with plastic to keep dust off. Keep the items out of sunlight to protect them from UV rays. Prevent plastic items from freezing as it can make the plastic brittle. When you're ready to go again, you're equipment should be just like the last time you used it.

Comment: Do you mean loosely wrap/cover items with plastic sheets or bags, or wrap them tightly (sealed) with food-type plastic wrap?

Comment: As long as they're properly cleaned to remove all food (beer in this case) residue, there should be no need to wrap them tightly. Make sure everything is completely dry before covering or you may cause mold/mildew issues. A loose covering is all that is needed to keep dust off. The washing, sanitizing, and drying will keep things from growing on it.